# What is causing the error "more than one linestring in KML"

Tags: kml, mapinfo, google-earth, linestring

I exported a KML from Mapinfo as a single combined line, however when i try to uploaded into a different mapper I get an error indicating that there are multiple linestring tags in my KML.  I can see it as a single line in google earth, and when i export it from Mapinfo its exported as a single object.

It was originally a route created from multiple segments which i combined into a single segment using the combine tool in mapinfo.

Why does it say that i have multiple line string tags?

Comment: What "mapper" are you trying to open it in, and does it have full KML support?  Can you share the KML or a sample so we can help debug?  Have you looked at the actual KML/XML tags in a text editor?  The original segments are probably still encoded as individual LineStrings, or combined as a MultiGeometry (which should be valid KML, though not all software supports it). Or maybe they were incorrectly combined into the same Placemark geometry, or some other issue.

Comment: Also note that even though you have combined the lines into one object in MapInfo Pro, that one line can still be made up of multiple sections. That would be the case if the lines you are combining don't touch.